# Getting distance from center to top right corner in Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I searched and found that we can get distance for the pink line.
so is there anyway to get distance from center to top right corner of google map directly?
Or anyway to get distance for the blue line.

[image: Google map]

Comment: Do you want the distance in pixels, km, miles, some other unit?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain the bounds (the coords for your visible map)  using

```
  bounds =  map.getBounds();
```

once you have the bounds you can extract the coord you need

```
  ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

for the distiance you could use the geometry library from google maps and the computeDistanceBetween() function

```
  google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (latLngA, latLngB);
```

and last you can obtain the center of the map  using

```
myCenter = map.getCenter();
```

and as sample

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (ne, myCenter);
```

Comment: To some degree yes, but the distance between center and corner is not exactly half the distance between corners, unless you're looking at the equator line. This is, however, a valid aproximation when dealing with closer zooms.

Comment: @amenadiel  .. correct  .. but in google map there also a function for get the center()  .. then the OP can use this coord as one of the point  .. and obtain a correct spherical distince for  all points  .. anyway answer  updated with get center too

Comment: Yes, that's the correct approach. Howerver your answer needs an edit. You should get the coordinates of north-west corner, and compute distance to map center.